# Entry Point in Spring

Tags: spring

I am working on a codebase which uses Spring dependency injection framework. I was checking the spring but I am unable to find how Spring XML files gets executed as the first thing in code. Who defines this entry point? Like in code, I know main() method is the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The Application Context is Spring's advanced container.

spring it's container . entry point it's ApplicationContext . 
The ApplicationContext includes all functionality of the BeanFactory, It is generally recommended over BeanFactory. BeanFactory can still be used for lightweight applications like mobile devices or applet-based applications.

**The most commonly used ApplicationContext implementations are : **

FileSystemXmlApplicationContext − This container loads the definitions of the beans from an XML file. Here you need to provide the full path of the XML bean configuration file to the constructor.

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext − This container loads the definitions of the beans from an XML file. Here you do not need to provide the full path of the XML file but you need to set CLASSPATH properly because this container will look like bean configuration XML file in CLASSPATH.

You can run container with your xml config :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
         ("FILE PATH TO application-context.xml");
      --application-context.xml - is your cofing file
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.getMessage();
   }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext 
         ("classthat:/application-context.xml");
      --application-context.xml - is your cofing file
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.getMessage();
   }
```

By default, ApplicationContext implementations **eagerly create** and configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process. eagerly means that all beans that were not marked as lazy will be created as spring container started.

Comment: Hi. For spring boot application, what could be the best solution to discover the entry point?